# Assertion Error while running inference in tensorflow lite

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run an inpainting model that takes image as and input and gives image in the form of output. When I run the android application I get the following error:

```
2020-02-06 15:01:39.308 2143-2143/com.example.inpainting A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc" failed
2020-02-06 15:01:39.308 2143-2143/com.example.inpainting A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2143 (mple.inpainting)
```

Please advise a suitable solution.